# Email Broken Character in Japan

Tags: php, email, encode

Does anyone know how to get Japanese or other double-byte character sets to appear correctly in email? 
I'm sending Japanese in email. While I can see the characters, people in Japan have been telling me that they cannot see the characters. That's kind of makes my emails useless @_@ 
I've tried setting all kinds of character sets in the web.config and in the CDO config, but haven't found out how to get the characters to display properly.

Comment: already tested that. didn't work. it work fine on other email in japan. but in these emails ex. ezweb.ne.jp, docomo.ne.jp, i.softbank.jp, softbank.ne.jp. that didn't work

Comment: If you're sending to a feature phone you probably need to use the iso-2022-jp encoding.

Comment: i already tried that and it's not working either

Comment: It's possible you're sending characters that aren't supported in iso-2022-jp, or it's possible the recipients have software that doesn't support it. Try re-asking specifying the encodings you tried, an example message that doesn't work, the code you used to send the mail, and what software the recipients use to read the mail. Unfortunately there's no answer that just works for everything, so you'll need to be specific.